# What is the meaning of 以 in 以 ... 來 pattern?

Tags: grammar

What is the literal meaning of 以 in 以 ... 來 pattern like in the following sentence: 以我的情況來看. What is the syntactic role of this word (verb, particle, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[以 ... 來 + (v)] = [with/ according to/ base on ... to + (v)]

[**以**]我的情況[*來*]看 = [*to*] assess it [**base on**/ according to] my situation

[**以**]我的想法[*來*]說 = [*to*] judge it [**with**/ according to] my thinking

[**以**]他的指示[*來*]做標準 = [*to*] make standards [**according to**/ with] his instruction

When you can replace 以 with 從 in your sentence, 以 means 'from'

When you can replace 以 with 用 in your sentence, 以 means 'with'

When you can replace 以 with 跟據 in your sentence, 以 means 'according to'

Comment: Is it  possible to provide the literal meaning of 

以 word? For example, the particle 把 in sentence 我把車輛賣掉了 can be translated as "take, grab". So, the whole sentence is literally translated as "I took the car and sold it". Also, what about 以?

Comment: 以 can literally be translated as 'with'

Comment: thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Your 'sentence' is a phrase. On its own doesn't really tell us much. It needs a bit more.

以我的情況來看， 我明天去不了浙江。
In my present situation, I don't think I will be able to go to Zhejiang tomorrow.

以我的经济情況來看， 我买不了这辆S600奔驰。
In my present economic situation, I don't think I can afford to buy this S600 Mercedes.

How you translate 以 will always depend on the context. There are no hard and fast rules. Oftentimes it won't get translated.

PS： 我把車輛賣掉了 does not mean "I took the car and sold it"

我把那輛車賣掉了 = 我卖掉了那辆车。= I sold that car.

If you ask a Chinese friend to translate "I sold that car.", he or she will probably tell you:

我把那辆车卖掉了。Chinese people prefer this word order I find. Why? 不知道！

Quite why Chinese uses 把 to achieve a different syntax I don't know, but this 把 or 将 or sometimes 给 don't contribute any meaning, they just allow for a different word order.

Answer (score 0):

以我的情況來看 - In my case ... I think, we need more, because what you give is not the whole sentence.